# Label doesn't align on left unless its width matches parent's width

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is the code I'm using fro this simple GUI:

```
def main():

    DOCROOT_LABEL = 'Document root:'
    PORT_LABEL = 'Listen on port:'
    APPNAME = 'PIPlayD'
    TEXT_HEIGHT = 1
    MF_WIDTH = 400
    MF_HEIGHT = 150

    # Loading main window
    win = Tkinter.Tk(baseName = APPNAME)
    win.wm_title(APPNAME)

    # Setting main frame
    f = Tkinter.Frame(win, width = MF_WIDTH, height = MF_HEIGHT)
    f.pack_propagate(False)


    # Setting labels
    label_DocRoot = Tkinter.Label(f,
                                  width = len(DOCROOT_LABEL),
                                  anchor = Tkinter.W,
                                  justify = Tkinter.LEFT,
                                  text = DOCROOT_LABEL)

    label_Port = Tkinter.Label(f,
                               width = len(PORT_LABEL),
                               anchor = Tkinter.W,
                               justify = Tkinter.LEFT,
                               text = PORT_LABEL)

    # Setting text areas
    text_DR = Tkinter.Text(f, height = TEXT_HEIGHT)

    text_P = Tkinter.Text(f, height = TEXT_HEIGHT)

    f.pack()
    label_DocRoot.pack()
    text_DR.pack()
    label_Port.pack()
    text_P.pack()

    win.mainloop()
```

I've set it to take the length of the string as its width, I've set its anchor property to W and justify it to left (although, as far as I've understood, justify should not be necessary since it controls how it aligns when a carriage return occur).

Now, I've noticed that if I change `len(DOCROOT_LABEL` to `MF_WIDTH`, to match the frame width, it aligns correctly.

So, how to align widget which width doesn't matches parent's width inside the frame?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to place the labels at the left side of the frame. The problem with your approach is that you merely align the text *within* the labels, but not the labels themselves, which are much smaller than the frame -- this can easily be seem by setting their `background` color differently.

You can fix this by using the `fill` parameter: `label_DocRoot.pack(fill="x")`. However,  I'd recommend using a different layout manager, e.g. the more flexible [`grid`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/grid.html) method.

```
f.grid()
label_DocRoot.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=Tkinter.W)
text_DR.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=Tkinter.W)
label_Port.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=Tkinter.W)
text_P.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=Tkinter.W)
```

By changing the values for `row` and `column` you can also place the labels in the same line and to the left of the text fields, which looks even better.

Also note that instead of `Text` you should use the [`Entry`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry.html) widget for single lines of text.

Answer (score 0):

if you would rather continue packing the labels into the canvas, there is an alternative. instead of anchoring the text within the label, try to anchor the label by setting the anchor in pack().

```
label_DocRoot.pack(anchor = Tkinter.W)
label_Port.pack(anchor = Tkinter.W)
```